# Can't find SharedResource using Localization in Razor Pages

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I've followed a pattern used in Razor Views, but when using Razor Pages it doesn't find the resource. Do I need to implement it differently?

**Startup.cs**:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddLocalization(o => {
        o.ResourcesPath = "Resources";
    });

    services.AddMvc()
        .AddViewLocalization(LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix, options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources")
        .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization();

}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseStaticFiles();

    app.UseRequestLocalization(new RequestLocalizationOptions {
        DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("no"),
        SupportedCultures = this.SupportedCultures,
        SupportedUICultures = this.SupportedCultures
    });

    app.UseMvc();
}

private IList<CultureInfo> SupportedCultures
{
    get
    {
        return new List<CultureInfo>
        {
            new CultureInfo("no"),
            new CultureInfo("en")
        };
    }
}
```

**_ViewImports.cshtml**:

```
@using FFU.Home.Galaxy;
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Localization;

@namespace FFU.Home.Galaxy.Pages

@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@addTagHelper *, LC.Tools.Utility.TagHelpers

@inject IViewLocalizer _local
@inject IHtmlLocalizer<SharedResources> _shared
```

**_Layout.cshtml**:

```
<title>@_shared.GetString("Title") - Friends For Understanding</title>
```

_shared.GetString("Title").ResourceNotFound is True

the folder Resources contains two files named *SharedResources.en.resx* and *SharedResources.no.resx*